# How do rename virsh disk-only snapshots?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, virsh

I created a few snapshots with `virsh snapshot-create-as --name "yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2 --disk-only --domain my-vm.qcow2` and made a bit of a mess with the snapshot image filenames.  It appears that appending `.qcow2` causes it to chain the spanshot filenames like:

```
my-vm.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.yyyymmdd-snap.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
....
```

Ideally, I'd like to see:

```
my-vm.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
my-vm.yyyymmdd-snap.qcow2
....
```

I know now to create snapshots without `.qcow2` in the future, but how I can clean up the current snapshot filenames without breaking my VM?

**EDIT**

Apparently, appending `.qcow2` isn't what caused the filename chaining.  I don't know why it did that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know with qcow2, but for VMware snapshots the images has the name of the parent disk on the first lines of the file, if you change them you can rename the snapshot name also.

Second option, merge them: https://blog.programster.org/qemu-img-cheatsheet